# "Is the sun shrinking currently?" vs "Does the sun shrinking currently?"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

I saw this question titled "Is the sun shrinking currently?" on astronomy SE, then I was wondering could I use the word "does" instead of "is"? Then I give Textranch a try, but they only double lined the latter phrase and didn't give an explanation. So why is the phrase  "Does the sun shrinking currently?" incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question why "**does**" is incorrect is because it is the third person present tense of "***do***" and hardly makes sense in this sentence, because you have already referred to the present time frame using the word "*currently*". "**is**" is denoting the continuity of the process (a continuation of the process in the present time), whereas "**does**" refers to an instant of the time.

One can rephrase the sentence as "Does the sun shrink?". Now that sounds more like a brick on the face, as if the sun always shrinks or it does not, no alternative answer.